# Play a sound from tab fragment with viewpager after a swipe gesture

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer, custom-adapter

I am trying to have a sound play on each swipe gesture i have 3 tabs using fragment and viewpager with custom pager adapter, i am running into an error cannot resolve method on the mediaplayer where my sound file is! so far i have tried to create a playSound method and have put the media code in there but everything i try is throwing error! i just want to simply play a sound when user swipes the pages, i have added the mp.start(); in the getitem method and it just doesnt work for me! greatly appreciate someone helping me solve this!

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import java.util.Locale;


public class ma_pager_adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{


    public ma_pager_adapter(FragmentManager fm ) {
        super(fm);


    }


    //reference to my soundfile
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.short_whoosh2);

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                tab1 t1 = new tab1();
                return t1;
            case 1:
                tab2 t2 = new tab2();
                return t2;
            case 2:
                tab3 t3 = new tab3();
                return t3;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }//set the number of tabs

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Top stories";
            case 1:

                return "Members";
            case 2:

                return "Setting";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       if(position == 0){
           mp.start();
       }if(position == 1){
            mp.start();
        }if(position == 2){
            mp.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getItem` is called when it is needed to create fragment, not when it's time to show it.
It's better to make [onPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) for your viewpager in activity and play a sound in `onPageSelected`.

Comment: hi, i have still not managed to solve this after all this time, would the onPageChangedListener go in the above mpager adapter class or on the single fragments? and if it is the above class then could you kindly show me how to implement this?
thank you